# Ruby on Rails: partial view inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, partial-views

I want to get next thing...

```
    # For ArticlesController > ApplicationController
    # in view
    render 'articles/edit/form'
    # tries 'app/views/articles/edit/_form.html.erb'
    # then tries 'app/views/articles/_form.html.erb'
    # then what it wants
```

Or maybe render with array `partial` option:

```
    # For ArticlesController > ApplicationController
    # in view
    render_exists ['articles/edit/form', 'articles/new/form']
    # tries 'app/views/articles/edit/_form.html.erb'
    # then tries 'app/views/articles/new/_form.html.erb'
    # then what it wants
```

This isn't realized, is this? But maybe some gems for 3.2 or monkeypatches... And don't you know pull requests to `rails` about it? Thanks!

**UPD** That's isn't controller-based view inheritance. This should work for (at the same page):

```
    render `articles/edit/form`
    render `comments/edit/form`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the mechanism I described in [an article in the rails forum](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=12204)

It works a treat for me though I hear there is now some built in support in the latest versions or at least effort is under way to do add such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

That already exists, and it's very similar to the controller inheritance.

You must follow a conventional strategy, however. You would put your global partial in `app/views/application`, then you can put a more specific one at each inherited level, like `app/views/articles`.

Take a look at the following railscast for more details: [#269 Template Inheritance](http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance)

Comment: I know. That's else. I'm `owner` for one object in page but `guest` for other. I.e. two comments and the first is mine. For `comment`s `edit` form is not equal to `new` form but they are equal for `article`s.